# Run java from PHP script

Tags: java, php

I try to run java from PHP but I can't even if I use absolute path to java executable (C:\Windows\System32\java.exe).

I found that the problem is PHP can't access this file, for some reason. I try:

```
<?php var_dump(file_exists('C:\Windows\System32\java.exe')); // returns false.
```

File actually exists and I (user under who I run php script) has permission to read and execute it.
It is very strange because I can execute notepad.exe and

```
<?php var_dump(file_exists('C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe')); // returns true.
```

Any ideas?

```
php -v 
PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Jul 10 2013 20:36:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

OS Windows 7 64bit

PHPinfo:

phpinfo()
    PHP Version => 5.3.27

```
System => Windows NT IT8 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Business Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date => Jul 10 2013 20:35:35
Compiler => MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture => x86
Configure Command => cscript /nologo configure.js  "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20090626
PHP Extension => 20090626
Zend Extension => 220090626
Zend Extension Build => API220090626,NTS,VC9
PHP Extension Build => API20090626,NTS,VC9
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar, ssh2.shell, ssh2.exec, ssh2.tunnel, ssh2.scp, ssh2.sftp
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters => convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.*
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run java using php you have to use php-jaja-bridge.see here:http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

for more help see this:
http://darrylclarke.com/2008/03/04/installing-php-java-bridge-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion:
from PHP.net to file_exists:
`This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.`

Further:
Result of `file_exists` will be cached.
 Maybe you have to call `clearstatcache()`

**EDIT**:
You may try following:
 `<?php var_dump(file_exists("C:\\Windows\\System32\\java.exe"));`

Comment: safe_mode is disabled in my php.ini
clearstatcache() didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem and resolved the issue by relocating java.exe
from the Windows/System32 folder to e.g. C:/Java
(Assuming the executable file C:/Java/java.exe now actually exists) 'file_exists("C:/Java/java.exe")' (and 'is_executable("C:/Java/java.exe")')
should now return true.